# Create a 2-channel numpy file from two cvs file containing a 9x9 matrix

Tags: python

I would like to take two .cvs file (each is a 9x9 matrix) from a folder with the same name and create a unique numpy file of the size 9x9x2 and save it in another folder.

This is my code, where the problem is that the final file right now has been saved as a 9x18 instead of 9x9x2.

```
import os, glob
from collections import defaultdict

dirs = ['/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Nuova cartella/mu1/real', '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Nuova cartella/mu1/imag']
file_pattrn = r'*.csv'
unique_files = defaultdict(list)

for d in dirs:
  for i in glob.iglob(os.path.join(d, file_pattrn)):
     unique_files[os.path.basename(i)].append(i)

destination = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/New_Dataset'
for unique_filename, copies in unique_files.items():
  with open(os.path.join(destination, unique_filename), 'w') as f:
      for copy in copies:
          with open(copy, 'r') as cp:
            for line in cp:
                f.write(line)
```

Comment: Please include a [MRE] with example input and expected output. What is a *2-channel numpy file*?

Comment: 2-channel means that I would like to obtain an array of size 9x9x2, it's like a concatenation of array along the third direction or second direction according to python language.